# nodejs query azure storage table according to timestamp

Tags: node.js, azure, timestamp, azure-table-storage

I successfully query the table with Partition Key by using the query:

```
var query= new azure.TableQuery().where('PartitionKey ne ?','test');
```

But I tried to query with the timestamp but failed.

```
var query=new azure.TableQuery().where('Timestamp ge ?', azure.TableUtilities.entityGenerator.DateTime(new Date(Date.UTC(2014,11,11,00,00,00))));
```

I think the DateTime is the SDK for Nodejs. But I'm not sure why it's not correct. The error is the query if wrong. Can anyone help me with that? Thanks.

Comment: Just try by prefixing your date/time value with `datetime`. Something like `Timestamp ge datetime'2014-11-11T00:00:00Z'`.

Comment: Yes, this query works in the azure storage table. But I want to use the query in nodejs. And I tried where('Timestamp ge ?', datetime'2014-11-11T00:00:00Z' )but still didn't work

Comment: I don't think you should be using entityGenerator as it creates an object of type entity. Could now the error be because your where clause is in single quotes? Try something like `where("Timestamp ge datetime?", '2014-11-11T00:00:00Z')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to create table queries in the Azure Storage Node.js library. If you take a look at the [TableQuery](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/table/tablequery.js) class in the [Azure Storage Node.js GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node) repository you'll find several examples on how to construct queries in the `.where()` method docs. Two ways of doing your query are below:

- `var tableQuery = new TableQuery().where(TableQuery.dateFilter('Timestamp', QueryComparisons.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, dateVal));`
- `var tableQuery = new TableQuery().where('Timestamp >= ?date?’, dateVal);`

Comment: Just to save anybody else some time. the second way worked for me. `dateVal` could simply be a `new Date(1,0,4)` object.

Comment: I am trying the same code but with azure cosmos db table api. The query is not returning me any records. Can anyone guide me if there is any particular reason as to why it's not working?