# Query on the basis of Timestamp Azure Storage Table/Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: node.js, azure, timestamp, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage

I am trying to query the entities in Azure Cosmos DB table on the basis of Timestamp using azure table storage SDK for node.js

The timestamp I have in DB is following

[image]

and in code I am querying creating the filter like this

```
const filter = storage.TableQuery.dateFilter(
    "Timestamp",
    storage.TableUtilities.QueryComparisons.GREATER_THAN,
    new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 0, 1))
);

query = new TableQuery().where(filter);
```

But no results are being returned for me.

I have googled a bit and found the following stack overflow question as well

[nodejs query azure storage table according to timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198972/nodejs-query-azure-storage-table-according-to-timestamp)

Both solutions in it's answer are not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample code works for me, as below, which you can refer to try again. Hope it helps.

I installed Azure Storage SDK for Node.js via command [`npm i azure-storage`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-storage)

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var tableService = azure.createTableService('<your storage account>','<your storage key>');
```

There are two ways to build a query object.

1. Directly use `where` function with filter template string and values.

   ```
   var query = new azure.TableQuery().where('Timestamp ge ?', new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 0, 1)));
   ```
2. First build a filter expression, then to generate a query object.

   ```
   var filter = azure.TableQuery.dateFilter('Timestamp', azure.TableUtilities.QueryComparisons.GREATER_THAN, new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 0, 1)));
   var query = new azure.TableQuery().where(filter);
   ```

Finally, to query table entities.

```
console.log(query);
tableService.queryEntities('<your table name>', query, null, function(error, result, response) {
  if(!error) {
    // query was successful
    console.log(result);
  }
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Can you share the version of your azure-storage npm package?
Mine is ~2.10.3 and not sure if you have any earlier version and new version has some breaking change

Comment: @UmairFarooq It's `azure-storage@2.10.3` as same as yours, which I show it via `npm list`.

Comment: The only difference I have from this answer is overload of createTableService. Your answer has storage account name and access key in the createTableService instead of connection string which is of cosmos db table api account in my case.

When I go to storage account (of same resource group as my cosmos db) and go to storage explorer, there is a new set of tables and the cosmos db table which I am trying to query is not here. I created a table, added a record and tried the above example and it is now querying data from there. 

Can you guide me why it doesn't work with cosmos db table api?